# gSOAP is not working when encoding is document/literal

Tags: gsoap

I am using gSOAP framework to create web service in C++ but it is not working when encoding used is document/literal .Below is the header file .

```
class ListOfIntegers { public:std::list<int> numList; } ;

//gsoap product service name: product
//gsoap product service protocol: SOAP
//gsoap product service style: document
//gsoap product service encoding: literal
//gsoap product service namespace: ns


//gsoap product schema namespace : product
//gsoap product service method : get products

int product_GetProduct(ListOfIntegers productIdentifiers ,ListofCSProduct& lstProd);
```

following command is run on above header file.

```
soapcpp2 -i -S -I<pathToImportFolder> Services.h
```

After buiding this , when i hit the API , it ignores the input parameter passed to it.

On enabling the gSOAP logs i could see below log snippets.

```
Begin tag found (level=4) 'prod:ProductIdentifiers'='product:ProductIdentifiers'
Enter id = '' type=8 location = 00000001234 size = 32
Unexpected element 'prod:numList' in input(level =4 ,1)
Tags prod"numList' and SOAP-ENV:' match but namespace differ
IGNORING element 'prod:numList'
End Tag found (level=5) 'prod:numList'='
```

Tried many things but it is not working. Can anyone have any pointer for this issue . am i missing anything.

Please note this service works fine when style/encoding is rpc/encoded.

Comment: There isn't much info in your post to make a suggestion and the log looks like it is missing a crucial part. It seems that doc/lit is not used but rather HTTP directly. Perhaps the protocol declaration is set to HTTP or POST instead of SOAP?

Comment: I noticed that you are missing an underscore in `product_GetProduct` which should be `product__GetProduct`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected example (I don't see any `ListOfCSProduct` class so I added one):

```
//gsoap product service name: product
//gsoap product service protocol: SOAP
//gsoap product service style: document
//gsoap product service encoding: literal
//gsoap product service namespace: ns

//gsoap product schema namespace: product
//gsoap product service method: get products

class ListOfIntegers { public: std::list<int> numList; } ;
class ListOfCSProduct { public: std::list<std::string> strList; } ;

int product__GetProduct(ListOfIntegers productIdentifiers, ListOfCSProduct& lstProd);
```

Compile and test the spec and the generated source code:

```
$ soapcpp2 -ST product.h
$ c++ -o testserver soapTester.cpp soapServer.cpp soapC.cpp stdsoap2.cpp
$ ./testserver < product.GetProduct.req.xml

Status: 200 OK
Server: gSOAP/2.8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 428
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:product="product">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<product:GetProductResponse>
<lstProd></lstProd>
</product:GetProductResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The test uses the XML request message generated by soapcpp2, which is just a dummy example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:product="product">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <product:GetProduct>
   <productIdentifiers>
    <numList>0</numList>
   </productIdentifiers>
  </product:GetProduct>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

To implement a service, define a `product__GetProduct()` function or method.